# Segmentation fault (core dumped) C++ error Process returned 139 (0x8B)

Tags: c++

can someone please explain what's wrong with this code? I'm getting this error in console when I try to run the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = {2,1,9,4,4,56,90,3};

    int target = 8;

    unordered_map<int,int> m;

    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        m[nums[i]] = i;
    }

    int req_num;

    for (int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
        req_num = target - nums[i];

        auto search = m.find(req_num);
        int first = search->first;
        int second = search->second;
        if(first == req_num && second != i){
            cout << second << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If someone can point out my error and explain what I did wrong, that'd be of great help!!

I tried running the program multiple times thinking it might be a build error. I'm getting the same result.

It was working fine until I changed map from ordered to unordered.

Comment: How sure are you that `find` found?

Comment: `if (search == m.end()) continue;`

Comment: In the first iteration of the second for loop you've got `req_num = 8 - 2`, i.e. `6`. You haven't inserted 6 into the map though, so `m.find(req_num)` returns the end iterator and dereferencing this iterator results in undefined behaviour. This is not a compiler error btw.

Comment: Changing `map` to `unordered_map` won't change the correctness of the code, but may have a huge effect on the visibility of the undefined behaviour from accessing the contents of the `end` iterator.

Comment: Interesting. UBSan didn't even see the mistake in the `map` version: https://godbolt.org/z/7v9GEqEn7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you are doing two sum question. The reason for segmentation fault is find() may not always find your req_num in the map. By solving this problem, I modified your code and it works properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = {2,1,9,4,4,56,90,3};

    int target = 8;

    unordered_map<int,int> m;

    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        m[nums[i]] = i;
    }

    int req_num;

    for (int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
        req_num = target - nums[i];

        auto search = m.find(req_num);
        if(search == m.end()) continue;
        int first = search->first;
        int second = search->second;
        if(first == req_num && second != i){
            cout << second << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I also modified your code to make more sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = {2,1,9,4,4,56,90,3};

    int target = 8;

    unordered_map<int,int> m;

    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        m[nums[i]] = i;
    }

    int req_num;

    for (int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
        req_num = target - nums[i];

        if(m.find(req_num) != m.end()){
            if(m[req_num]!=i){
                cout << m[req_num] << endl;
            }
        };

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I was doing the two sum problem. It was easy to implement in Python but I had a hard time doing it in C++. And yes your modified code makes much more sense.